# Ethereum account code hash

Tags: contract-deployment, accounts, state-trie

I've created a contract
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xfaba4475358c1c23e37549f9bd54300261873d41#code

And using its  createChild() method 
I've created 3 children

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x79700787ed34aacd736a14f65d46bcfda61b3e9a#internaltx
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x617214e49c2e31d1a5afa05b1acf8868598e51ce#code
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x306d7eb3fc1fe3ea09b216f193f2dc10e89698d9#code

Every child contains exacly same code

My question is

Why gas price of creation of every of this 3 children contracts is high (200k gas)
If only first contains unique code ?

Second and third account should have exacly same code hash
in account state tree 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/afWDt.jpg

the state database should have only one entry and 3 accounts pointing to it (code is immutable) so gas costs of second and third creation should be much lower since there is no new code written to blockchain only new account created.

Answer (score 1):

The gas cost for deploying a contract does not depend on whether the code is unique, so what you're seeing is expected.